# OpenCV Autocropping a thumb from covered camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing, crop

Problem: My thumb has partially covered one side of my video/photo. What OpenCV tools can detect the maximum x pixel index of the thumb (x_t) and perform a crop to keep the region: [x_t:W, 0:H]. Basically, remove the entire rectangle where the thumb exists to keep the remaining rectangular video. This can be performed once at the beginning of the video and the parameters can be retained.

Thoughts: The thumb appears blurry up close, so a contrast boundary detector is not as robust as I would like. BackgroundSubtraction over the first few frames seems promising, but I can't guarantee the video will be changing. Any other approaches?

Comment: why can't you just define a constant region? I don't see any need for fancy image processing here to find your thumb.

Comment: I agree with Piglet.

Comment: I can, I just need to determine what that constant region is programmatically. In my use-case, I'm not able to look at the video and determine where the thumb is (the occlusion is not actually a thumb -- but, it's similar and I figured people would be more familiar with the thumb problem)